# character(0) return when using RODBC

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I am trying to import some data directly into R from a SQL Database. I have set up the connection without an issue but extracting the data has been somewhat challenging. I will try and make this as clear as possible because I don't think I can make it reproducible due to some sensitive information. When I run the following line I get the data I wanted:

```
myconn <- odbcConnect("COMPANYNAME", uid = "support", pwd = "password111?")
sqlQuery(myconn, "SELECT * FROM Metrics")
```

However, when I include a specific database I want to extract from within the server I get an issue:

```
sqlQuery(myconn, "USE companyname_clientname SELECT * FROM Metrics")
```

Where companyname_clientname is the database. Instead of the data I want, I get

```
character(0)
```

I know that introducing "USE companyname_clientname" is the issue, I just don't know why or how to fix it. If there is anything that would make this easier for you to help me let me know and I will accommodate.

Comment: ODBC connections will only support a sort of "lowest common denominator" SQL syntax. I'm not terribly familiar with sql server; would `FROM companyname_clientname.Metrics` be equivalent?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not equivalent. What do you mean by "lowest common denominator" SQL Syntax?

Comment: I just mean that ODBC is meant to work with virtually _every_ SQL db out there, so many of the language extensions particular to a certain db won't work. I wouldn't count on anything beyond plain old select, insert, update and delete.

Comment: If anything's going to work, I would guess it would be changing the name of the db you connect to in `odbcConnect`, but that's just speculation.

Comment: Yeah I'll try through `odbcConnect`

Comment: Is the `USE` query separate from the `SELECT` query? If so, does inserting a semicolon between the queries help?

Comment: The semicolon didn't help, I still received the output of `character(0)`

Answer (score 13):

I had this same issue and found that there were 2 contributing reasons:

1. Like others pointed out, SET NOCOUNT ON needs to be at the start of your query
2. That alone didn't fix the issue of returning a character(0). I found that my SQL query also had a PRINT statement outputting a variable for debugging purposes. Removing the PRINT statement then successfully returned an output, in my case a temp table.

Hope this helps others!

Comment: For me it was a `PRINT` statement in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone else comes across this issue, the `character(0)` can also be a result of warnings in SQL, such as

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

This can be fixed by including `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` at the top of the SQL script.

Comment: Another cause is a `USE <DatabaseName>` statement

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. The `character(0)` seems to be as a result of the SQL using loops which the RODBC doesnt complete.

The solution that got me right was to add `set nocount on` to the start of the SQL statement. If its the same issue, it should do the trick.

Comment: I had already tried that actually, it was in another post somewhere. Unfortunately it didn't fix my issue.